# MySQL recursive query depending on result

Tags: mysql

I have table of games.

```
id  |  team1   | team2  |  score1  |  score2  |  date
 1     Hawks     Ducks          1          2     2016-12-02
 2     Sharks    Flyers         3          0     2016-12-02
 3     Kings     Oilers         1          3     2016-12-03
 4     Leafs     Stars          4          3     2016-12-03
 5     Blues     Jets           2          5     2016-12-04
 ..    ..        ..            ..         ..     ..
```

I need to get minimum 10 games. How can I write MySQL query, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM games
WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND date < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If result of this query less than 10 rows, then

```
SELECT * FROM games
WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
  AND date < NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

If result of this query less than 10 rows, then

```
SELECT * FROM games
WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
  AND date < NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

etc...

Why so? Sometimes no any games in a week, sometimes lots of games everyday.

I want to write it only in one MySQL query.

Comment: why don't you use limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * , ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_of_game , NOW())) as 'diff_days'
FROM games 
ORDER BY diff_days
LIMIT 10
```

I have renamed your date column because date is a reserved word in MySQL.

I have created a sqlfiddle where you can check the behavior of the code:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33c381d/6

Comment: Excellent! And no recursion, as I thought!

Answer (score 0):

give this a chance: you can select how many days you want to chaeck in **interval N DAY**

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT g.*, (
    SELECT `date`
    FROM (
        select `date`,count(*) as cnt from games
        WHERE `date` > DATE(now() - interval 3 DAY)
        GROUP BY `date`
        HAVING cnt >= 10
        ORDER BY `date` DESC, count(*)
        LIMIT 1
    ) as tmp ) selected_day
FROM games g
) as total
WHERE `date` = selected_day;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * from (
    -> SELECT g.*, (
    ->     SELECT `date`
    ->     FROM (
    ->         select `date`,count(*) as cnt from games
    ->         WHERE `date` > DATE(now() - interval 3 DAY)
    ->         GROUP BY `date`
    ->         HAVING cnt >= 10
    ->         ORDER BY count(*), `date` DESC
    ->         LIMIT 1
    ->     ) as tmp ) selected_day
    -> FROM games g
    -> ) as total
    -> WHERE `date` = selected_day;
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
| id | name   | date       | selected_day |
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
|  9 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 10 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 11 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 12 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 13 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 14 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 15 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 16 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 17 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
| 18 | game 1 | 2016-12-03 | 2016-12-03   |
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

The subquery will get the date where 10 or more rows have:

```
mysql>         select `date`,count(*) as cnt from games
    ->         WHERE `date` > DATE(now() - interval 3 DAY)
    ->         GROUP BY `date`
    ->         HAVING cnt >= 10
    ->         ORDER BY count(*), `date` DESC
    ->         LIMIT 1
    -> ;
+------------+-----+
| date       | cnt |
+------------+-----+
| 2016-12-03 |  10 |
+------------+-----+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: No, you didn't understand. I need to increase N days recursively until I get minimum 10 rows. Sometime it may be 2 days, sometime 10 days.

Comment: in my sample i will get 1,2 and 3 days, sort it by days and mit it to 10. so if they are only 8 row with 1 day it will take the next 2 rows from 2 days. i will extend my answer in a few minutes

Comment: in your sample you not seen the rows from 1 day if there are less the 10 recorcds. is this correct

Comment: 1 DAY, 2 DAY, 3 DAY... it's hard code. What if 20 days?

Comment: @Daryn K. - i have update my answer. now you get 10 rows from the last N days (interval)  where you have 10 or more entries per per